# How to wait for database migrations to complete before starting tests in docker-compose.yml

Tags: unit-testing, docker, database-migration

In a docker-compose.yml file, I have 3 services. The first service is used to spin up a MySQL database. The second service is used to run several database migrations to create tables and seed data in the MySQL database created in the first service. The third service is used to run some node.js unit tests which need the MySQL database. The problem is that I need the unit tests to start only after database migrations are complete. But there is no way for me to know that.

I have tried using the depends_on configuration option in the unit tests service to make it depend on the database migration service, but as per Docker documentation, depends_on only guaranties that unit tests service starts after database migration service has started.

Answer (score 0):

The **depends_on** option allows you to control startup order only.
In order to check for *readiness*, you'll have to check it programmaticaly. You can either write a wrapper script that checks that your migration is done, or you can use existing tools such as [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it)

You can find more info on the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)

Comment: Hi Marc, thank you for your comment. But the problem with the migration service is that there is no port that I can pin to check if it is ready, since it just uses the MySQL database which is setup in the first service. Using wait-for-it only allows me to know if the database is ready, but there is no way for me to know if database migrations are complete.

Comment: Can't you check it by executing a SQL script ?

Comment: Hi Marc, yes, I think it is a solution. But one disadvantage is that I need to update the script each time I add a new migration. I am just wondering if there is an approach which avoids this.

Comment: Can't you run your migration script at the application startup ? For example, in Java, there are some lib that allows you to run your SQL migration script when the application start (see [flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) or [liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/) )